# typeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str - Trying to automate api request and save json response to csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import Workbook

leitor = pd.read_excel('cnpj.xlsx')

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
contador = 1

for i, CNPJ in enumerate(leitor["cnpj"]) :
    r = requests.get(f'ApiURL{CNPJ}').json()
    

    ws.cell(row=i+1, column=1).value = r['Result'][0]['BasicData']['OfficialName']
    ws.cell(row=i+1, column=2).value = r['Result'][0]['BasicData']['TaxIdNumber']
   > ws.cell(row=i+1, column=3).value = r['Result'][0]['Emails']['EmailAddress']
    

wb.save("teste.xlsx")
```

How can I fix this? and have a better way to do it?

The code is working fine to response with only one "Email"

The JSON response I got from the API, is a list of e-mails from the database

```
 "Emails":
            [
                {
                    "EmailAddress": "email1@terra.com.br",
                    "IsMain": true,
                    "IsRecent": false,
                    "IsActive": false,
                    "ValidationStatus": "UNKNOWN"
                },
                {
                    "EmailAddress": "email2@oi.com.br",
                    "IsMain": false,
                    "IsRecent": false,
                    "IsActive": false,
                    "ValidationStatus": ""
                },
                {
                    "EmailAddress": "s@yahoo.com",
                    "IsMain": false,
                    "IsRecent": false,
                    "IsActive": false,
                    "ValidationStatus": ""
                }
            ],
```

Comment: Where is `"Result"`  in your response json?

Comment: I hide it for the post, but thats ok

Comment: it is a type error. If we expect to receive a number, we cannot receive any other type of data, for example a string. In this line it seems that a tipp string is received and not an index number. `ws.cell(row=i+1, column=1).value = r['Result'][0]['BasicData']['OfficialName'] `

Answer (score 0):

It also happens to me once, for me I think it is because I have Dictionary in my list. So, I changed the whole structure.

Comment: You can share your solution? thanks for the time

Answer (score 0):

I noticed your `['Emails']` is a dictionary key, that contains a **list**, that contains multiple dictionaries inside it.

```
> ws.cell(row=i+1, column=3).value = r['Result'][0]['Emails']['EmailAddress']
```

I think you forgot to reference the list that's inside `['Emails']` (the one that contains the dictionaries), so I would change the line to:

```
ws.cell(row=i+1, column=3).value = r['Result'][0]['Emails'][0]['EmailAddress']
```

That `[0]` corresponds to the first dictionary in the list, so if you want to access the other ones, you just have to change the number.